# HBase Error - assignment of -ROOT- failure

Tags: database, nosql, hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I've just installed hadoop and hbase from cloudera (3) but when I try to go to http://localhost:60010 it just sits there continually loading.

I can get to the regionserver fine - http://localhost:60030... Looking at the master hbase server logs I can see the following.

Looks like a problem with the root region.

All of this is installed on a ext4 1TB partition running Ubuntu (Natty) 11. No cluster/other boxes).

Any help would be great!

```
11/05/15 19:58:27 WARN master.AssignmentManager: Failed assignment of -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to serverName=localhost,60020,1305452402149, load=(requests=0, regions=0, usedHeap=24, maxHeap=995), trying to assign elsewhere instead; retry=0
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to /127.0.0.1:60020 after attempts=1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:957)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.getServerConnection(ServerManager.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.sendRegionOpen(ServerManager.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager$TimeoutMonitor.chore(AssignmentManager.java:1605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Chore.run(Chore.java:66)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
    at $Proxy6.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:349)
    ... 8 more
11/05/15 19:58:27 WARN master.AssignmentManager: Unable to find a viable location to assign region -ROOT-,,0.70236052
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939088

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed this issue for anyone else who finds this. Was a problem with the host file (/etc/hosts). Need to remove entries relating to 127.0.1.1 COMPNAME - just put a hash (#) in front of this line and then restart all hadoop and hbase services.

More on the solution here: http://blog.nemccarthy.me/?p=110

Comment: Just to emphasis, 127.0.*1*.1 should be commented out of /etc/hosts, 127.0.0.1 localhost can stay there. Most likely you do want to keep a record for your local hostname, and 127.0.0.1 seems to play well with hbase. http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#loopback.ip

Comment: Ubuntu put that entry in /etc/hosts as a requirement to GNOME ( http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=316099 and http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution ). Instead of just removing it, try to replace it with another permanent IP.

Answer (score 5):

As per @Manav:

> *If you find yourself in a situation wherein you can't edit /etc/hosts, the following* >*workaround will also work:*
>
> *in conf/hadoop-env.sh add the following line:*

```
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) and HBase 0.92.1. These steps fixed my issue for my single server install:

1. Edit the `/etc/hosts`: change the IP address associated with the hostname so that it uses your LAN IP instead of `127.0.0.1`
2. Open `<HBASE_DIR>/conf/hbase-env.sh`
3. edit `HBASE_OPTS`, append `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`. The line should look like this:

   export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
4. Restart HBase

Comment: +1 the other answers didn't really work, this seems the most sane

Comment: same as Doug. This fixed it for me on macox.8 with homebrewed hbase.

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself in a situation wherein you can't edit /etc/hosts, the following 
workaround will also work:

in conf/hadoop-env.sh add the following line:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

(removed edit, moved as a separate answer)

Answer (score 1):

your hosts file should look like this

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
#127.0.1.1  ubuntu.ubuntu-domain    ubuntu
192.168.2.100   ubuntu
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This file can be found in /etc/hosts

Regards
Shuja

Answer (score 1):

Here's another work-around that Works For Me, if you're unwilling to alter `/etc/hosts` (since Ubuntu put that [entry there](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution) [for a reason](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=316099)).

As [this post](http://blog.devving.com/why-does-hbase-care-about-etchosts/) explains, the core problem is that the loopback interface has multiple IPs bound to it while hbase assumes there will be only one.  The resulting mismatch causes the master to think a region server has one IP (127.0.0.1), when it's really listening on another (127.0.1.1, the IP bound to the host's declared FQDN.)

Removing the `/etc/hosts` entry is one way to restore the one-interface-one-IP assumption.  Replacing `127.0.1.1` in `/etc/hosts` with a "real" permanent IP is another.  Finally, another is to create a new interface: drop this in the bottom of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Bind an interface solely for the default host FQDN IP, to fix reverse dns
auto eth0.1
iface eth0.1 inet static
pre-up ip link add eth0.1 name eth0.1 type bridge
address 127.0.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You should then be able to `sudo ifup eth0.1` and see it in `ifconfig`.  Restart hbase & you should be good to go.

If you happen to already be using `eth0.1` the pick another slot (i.e. `eth0.2`), it shouldn't matter.

**EDIT**: [@bcolyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934612/580412)'s use of `lo:0` also works for me, and is superior since loopback will always be available.  In that case the `pre-up` line also appears unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with a subinterface worked for me, but i used the loopback interface rather than eth0 because eth0 is not always available on my machine (external adapter) and i want it managed by NetworkManager (which refuses to manage eth0 if eth0.1 is defined in /etc/network/interfaces on ubuntu 13.04)

Relevant snippet:

```
auto lo:0
iface lo:0 inet static
address 127.0.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

in addition to the regular

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

of course

Answer (score 0):

In your hosts file to change host address from **127.0.1.1** to **127.0.0.1**