# Loopback interface value in windows OS

Tags: localhost, hbase, ipv6, ipv4, loopback

I had an issue with HBase services not bind to localhost. On checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939088/weird-dns-server-causes-hadoop-and-hbase-to-malfunction) post, I set 'lo' and issue resolved. (Earlier I tried with 'localhost' , '127.0.0.1' issue occurred still)

Now my question is, **To set loop back interface, 'lo' is the correct value in  windows?** [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) post tells that "Unix-like systems usually name this loopback interface lo or lo0."

In windows 'lo' has same functionality like in Unix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the java code from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html) to list the all available interface in Windows.

You can use "lo" in windows for loopback address.